# How to create a set of words from a string?

Tags: python

I'm writing my first program.

I need to know how to create a set of unique words from a string.

I want to know how to do this to be able to know the number of elements in the set (or the number of unique words in the string)

I would need this to happen:

*input:*

**string=("one one two three three four hello hello")**

*output:*

**("one", "two", "three", "four", "hello")**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We're happy to help you but would like to see what you've tried so far. To format code in your question use three ticks (```). 
While you're editing your question, have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split
It's also worth to try entering your questions in the search bar on stack overflow: "python split string" and "python array length" - maybe someone has already answered them.

Answer (score 2):

string has method 'split' which returns list of words splited by given parameter.

`string=("one one two three three four hello hello")
set_of_words = set(string.split(' ')`

output is :

`{'three', 'one', 'hello', 'two', 'four'}`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve the order of the words an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is the way to go:

```
import collections # OrderedDict is one Python's high-performance containers


string=("one one two three three four hello hello")


unique_word_dict = collections.OrderedDict() # creates and empty ordered dictionary

# The split method of strings breaks the string into parts using the specified separator.
# In this case the separator is a space character so each element in the list is a word.
word_list = string.split(' ') 

# This loops though each element of the list and makes the word a key in the OrderedDict. 
# The .get(word, 0) method creates a new key in the dictionary if it does not already
# exist and initializes it to 0.
# If the key already exists, .get(word, 0) returns the current value.

for word in word_list:
    unique_word_dict[word] = unique_word_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
    print('key: %s, value: %i' % (word, unique_word_dict.get(word)))


unique_words = tuple(unique_word_dict.keys())

print(unique_word_dict)
print(unique_words)
print(len(unique_words))
```

Output:

```
key: one, value: 1
key: one, value: 2
key: two, value: 1
key: three, value: 1
key: three, value: 2
key: four, value: 1
key: hello, value: 1
key: hello, value: 2
OrderedDict([('one', 2), ('two', 1), ('three', 2), ('four', 1), ('hello', 2)])
('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'hello')
5
```